# How to display a block only for an article with a specific node id?

Tags: nodes, blocks

I have quickly seen view reference and context module. Though they can display a view or block to a specific content type, I'm not sure if they can do it within a specific node.

As an example: I want to display a block only for an article with node id 3.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 3):

I would steer clear of using PHP for block visibility.  If you type something wrong you can break any number of things.

Just go to your block settings, and take a look at the vertical tabs at the bottom of the page.  The first option is *Pages*.  Just change the radio button to "*Only the listed pages*" and enter *node/3* in the box.

**EDIT**

If you use the [Views Reference](http://drupal.org/project/viewreference) module mentioned in your question, then you can quite easily embed a Views block as one of your fields just as any other field.  The field itself can't be exclusive to a node ID, only an entity type.  However, you could just leave it blank for the other entities of the same type and use [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) if you are worried about other people using the field incorrectly/at all.

One unrelated helpful hint with Views Reference - I generally tag my "reference-able" views with the same tag (i.e. Embeddable, Referenceable e.t.c.).  then you can easily select which Views to make available to the Views Reference field.

You MIGHT be able to embed blocks with [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) combined with [BEAN](http://drupal.org/project/bean) or [Boxes](http://drupal.org/project/boxes), but I'm not 100% sure.  Failing this you are probably looking at breaking up the entire `$content` variable in the template and embedding it yourself (which would mean much more maintenance if fields get added or removed), using Views and turning the whole content types into blocks that can be positioned (MUCH effort).

Comment: no my friend, lets suppose I want put a block between my node `body` . your method not ok with it.

Comment: I agree with Zhilevan because thats exactly is my purpose, put the block as part of the node content.

Comment: Aaah, I see.  The question could probably have been clearer.  Either way, you're going to need more help, as the `module_invoke()` part will still render the block outside of  your `$content` variable unless you break up the entire variable and render everything separately in the template.

Comment: Ah, I also read the other answer wrong at first - I thought you meant PHP for block vsibility on the settings page.  I'll have my coffee now and come back later ;-)

Comment: @Chapabu be appetite :)

Answer (score 1):

To render something inside a node body, you need an *input filter*  to be able to write something like `[block:foo:bar]` and have the `bar` block from the `foo` module rendered. Unfortunately, a dedicated module does seems to exists on Drupal.org. Actually, [one](http://drupal.org/project/block_filter) exists but is for Drupal 5 and has only a development release.

Using the PHP filter as suggested in others answers is an easy option. But this is a hacky one and not recommended. It opens to gate to a lot of abuses and potential headache debugging code stored in the database.

Comment: hacky? if php filter was hacky not cosider it as drupal core modules  :(. if roles with high permission admit use php filter there is no worring. at least it's implementable

Comment: If you search for it, you will find that a lot of stuffs in  core stuffs are considered hacky by core maintainers themselves. Just assist conversations at DrupalCons or follow issues in the issue queues. PHP filter is one of them. Yes it works, yes it allow site builders to quickly meets many needs. But for a developer this is a quick and (extremely) dirty solution that create hard to maintain website. It is also a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Insert Block](https://drupal.org/project/insert_block) module. Still in dev, but may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this to work using the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless:
>
> - Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
> - Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
> - What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) intercept the URL corresponding to your article, which appears to be a node, with `node id = 3`.

Adding a Rules Condition like "if it is `/node/3`" is really like a getting started with Rules Conditions. If needed, just copy (import) the Rules example included in my answer to "[How to make the permissions of a module more granular?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182326/how-to-make-the-permissions-of-a-module-more-granular)" and finetune it a bit to fit your needs.

Answer (score -2):

**NEW**

Enable `php filter` module ,  `add new content` in `body` section  do something like this picture [image: ScreenShot]

(load your module accrding below notes)

---

if we wanted to place this custom block into a page, we would simply substitute these values into our PHP code snippet (which we place in a node (page or other content type)) as follows:

```
Drupal 7

<?php
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 26);
print render($block);
?>
```

Drupal 6 And Earlier

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', 26);
print $block['content'];
?>
```

Notice that the middle two terms ('block', 'view') always stay the same. You're simply updating the first and last term.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do this when there are settings in the UI for exactly what the op wants.

Comment: THis might be "similar" to the link mentioned but what Im looking is a module than a snippet of code.

Comment: @ARGO, ok I am expain in another way, see the edit

Comment: There are huge caveats needed when using the PHP filter. It should not be promoted as a good tool to do everything including the kitchen sink on a Drupal website. Because it store code in the database it prevent proper version tracking of that code. Leading to maintenance and evolution nightmares. Because it allow administrator to write any code on the page, it can easily lead to borken pages (ie. PHP Fatal Error) or worse, broken site (broken code in a block/node displayed on all pages including admin pages) hard to investigate and harder to fix.